# CefSharp load a page with browser login

Tags: wpf, browser, load, cefsharp

I need to ebed a web browser in a Wpf app,  I tried with the one from the toolbox but get some issues and went to CefSharp.

```
public MainWindow()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings();
 Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());           
CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
  licence_grid.Children.Add(webBrowser);
  webBrowser.Address = "http://myurlToLoad the page";
}
```

The problem is when I used a normal url the page load.
But when I used the url I intend to use and whith which the user enter his user and password in a browser pop up (I mean not a pop up from the website) . I get an error with this page take yoo much time to load and nothing else.
Can someone give me some tracks to follow...
Thanks

Comment: What error are you seeing? Also there's some example projects to help you get started see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Try loading your web page using the example and see if you get a similar error. It's also helpful if you include the version of `CefSharp` as a general practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the popup you are referring to is in fact the site prompting for `basic` authentication.

In that case you need to provide an [`IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/cefsharp/IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials/cefsharp/oCLeWUwdiEw/L7WNkbR4neMJ) handler.

Comment: yes, I didn' find the right word.... So you mean I need to implement an handler and do by my self the prompt window, get the user and pwd and put vthese values in the string pass by ref in the handler...

Comment: Yep, basically provide the user with your own dialog to capture username and password then set the two ref params and return true;

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.cs#L59

Comment: Ok, many thanks, I'm coming from MS ActiveX so I need to discover, I found doc not so good..

Comment: have you implemented GetAuthCredentials and did it work

Comment: In fact I changed my mind and turn to Electron to develop my app

Comment: I implemented the GetAuthCredentials handler; inside of it put a modal Window to receive the user and password, but this is not working because of this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
This is the code placed in the handler:
AuthBox dlg = new AuthBox();
dlg.Owner = _parent;
dlg.ShowDialog();

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

As the question & answer is very old and i would like to give the latest update on this solution, there is slight change as per original solution suggested.

anybody consuming cefsharp need to implement the authentication dialog. and changes in method is

```
 bool IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, 
        string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
    {
        //NOTE: If you do not wish to implement this method returning false is the default behaviour
        // We also suggest you explicitly Dispose of the callback as it wraps an unmanaged resource.

        // shyam - original implemenation.
        //callback.Dispose();
        //return false;

        bool handled = false;

        // Instantiate the dialog box
        AuthDialog dlg = new AuthDialog(host); // create new dialog with username and password field.

        // Open the dialog box modally 
        dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (dlg.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // The user did not cancel out of the dialog. Retrieve the username and password.
            callback.Continue(dlg.UserName,dlg.Password);
            handled = true;
        }

        return handled;
    }
```

Comment: where is the AuthDialog class from? Visual studio cant find it.