# Cef Browser Wpf explore the dom, find elements and change values

Tags: wpf, dom, browser, cefsharp

Further to a post ([CefSharp load a page with browser login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612875)).
I implemented the `IRequestHandler` interface and the different methods, particularly the `GetAuthCredentials` where I show a dialog and recover user and password and passing it to the event handler.
Now I want to access to the dom where I get several `frameset` with differents `frames` and I'm interested in one `frame` which I know the `name` Atribute.
Inside this `frame` I need to get list of different type of `input` , `select` etc...
In my app I have a button which I use to set values of the different `elements` depending if they are present on the displayed page.
PROBLEM is I don't see any way of getting the `document`, the `frames` collection etc....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CefSharp` doesn't expose the underlying `DOM`, and is unlikely to see http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10652&p=19533#p16750

Your best bet is to use `EvaluateScriptAsync` and a combination of `Javascript Binding`

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-return-a-result
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

If you absolutely must have `DOM` access and cannot invent your way to a solution then `CefGlue` might be a better choice for you. (I should point out that the `DOM` can only be accesses in the `Render` process, and as such calls needed to be passed to the `Browser` process though `IPC`, so it isn't a trivial task).

Comment: Ok, I understand better the philosophy of the browser, which is ... a browser and not necessarily what I need and what I would yould like to have in such a component. I will experiment with Js script. Thanks