# Fetching HTML content from Angular4 page with HttpClient from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, html, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement to fetch content from angular4 data-grid and integrate to display in another website using iframe . my content is basically live devex data-grid that i want to display partially on another website.

What I want to do is parse and investigate HTML source code from some external Url. I am trying to do it with HttpClinet but unable to do.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(); 
request.Method = new HttpMethod("GET"); 
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:62217/ArrivalComponent"); 
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead); 
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In any case I am getting only basic HTML of this page. There is no HTML which comes from angular components in response. I am sure components are not loaded yet during request, and request is asynchronous so response is truncated.

can anyone guide me know what is the best approach to display partially my live data-grid to another site?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is no browser or HTML processor that executes the JavaScript of your SPA, `HttpClient` is just a component that emits HTTP requests and retrieves the answer, in this case a bare HTML.

The basic steps in order to retrieve the datagrid are

- Download the HTML page (the step you already did)
- Determine which additional resources you need to execute the Angular component (mostly JavaScript, assumedly)
- Download the additional resources
- Execute the JavaScript within the HTML to fill the table (probably with [JavaScript.NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net))

Anyway, I don't know how easy or hard Angular is with JS.Net. Futhermore you seem to be lacking the concepts of how HTML, JS and SPAs work, which could make the whole thing even more complicated.

Another option might be to use a component like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) (especially [CefSharp.OffScreen](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/)) to execute the page with all of its JS and somehow retrieve the resulting DOM from CefSharp. Unfortunately it seems as if you can't simply get the DOM from C#, but have to use the JavaScript bridge (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29662806/2249175)).